# Why does Chinese combine words with the same meaning to produce again the same meaning like 睡觉?

Tags: dictionary

I keep coming across words like 睡觉 which both mean to sleep and together mean to sleep. Are the dictionaries that I'm using adding the definition of the combined words to the single words possibly or is there another reason?

Comment: see e.g. previous question https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/31011/why-use-combined-characters-that-have-the-same-meaning/31012#31012

Comment: 睡觉 sleep, lie down to sleep 觉 jiào sleep is a bound morpheme

Comment: I have written [an answer to that question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/31288/15320), including a specific discussion about 睡觉.