# Difference between 學識 and 知識？

Tags: grammar, mandarin

According to these dictionary links, both 學識 and 知識 mean **knowledge**:

- [學識 - CantoDict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/search/?searchtype=1&text=%E5%AD%B8%E8%AD%98)
- [知識 (zi1 sik1 | zhi1 shi5) : knowledge; learning - CantoDict](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/6078/)

1. What's the difference between 學識 and 知識?
2. Which one would be used to translate this sentence: "He is a very knowledgeable person."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my answer to this question [认识 vs 知道 based on glyph origins](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22253/%e8%ae%a4%e8%af%86-vs-%e7%9f%a5%e9%81%93-based-on-glyph-origins/22264#22264)

> 見識: experience(v) = (see + know) *'to see to know'
>
> 見識: experience(n)= (see + knowledge) knowledge from what you had seen
>
> 學識: knowledge; acquirements (n) = (learn/study + know) knowledge from what you had studied
>
> 常識: common sense; general knowledge(n) = (common + knowledge) knowledge that is common

- **知**识 = **knowledge** that you **know**. (regardless of the source, you can gain it by study or experience ) in other words 学识 and 見识 are both 知识
- 学识 = **knowledge** or **acquirements** from what you had studied (as stated in my answer to the linked post)

> He is a very knowledgeable person

It can be translated as:

他是一个知识渊博的人

他是一个很有知识的人

meanwhile, 他是一个很有学识的人 would mean "He is a very academically knowledgeable person"

Comment: once again, a very elaborate and clear answer. many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**知识** is:

> knowledge

in general.

**学识** is more like:

> scholarly/academic knowledge

You see how the emphasis is on 学, perhaps you could think of it like *book smarts*.

To translate your sentence, on the other hand, I’d opt for something like:

> 见多识广

Which is to say that someone has seen a lot of stuff and knows lots of things.

“He is a knowledgeable person” could just simply be written: `他见多识广。`.

Answer (score 0):

知识 = knowledge
学识 = scholarly knowledge.