# What's a mnemonic for remembering the characters in 建议 and 意见?

Tags: characters, writing

This is a little bit embarrassing, considering I'm currently studying HSK6-level content, but I cannot memorize how to write the HSK4 words:

> 建议 (jiàn​yì​)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%BB%BA%E8%AE%AE): to propose / to suggest / to recommend / proposal / suggestion / recommendation / CL: 個｜个, 點｜点
>
> 意见 (yì​jiàn​)
> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E6%84%8F%E8%A7%81): idea / opinion / suggestion / objection / complaint / CL: 點｜点, 條｜条

So...

**Question**: What's a mnemonic for remembering the characters in 建议 and 意见?

Comment: 建议: to build (建) an argument (议). May think of 建议 as being *constructive*.
意见: the opinion (n. 见) of sb's mind (意).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember:

建立 - erect

议論 - theory

建议 (raise theories) --> **to suggest** (v) --> **suggestion** (n)

~

意 - mind

见 - see

**意见** (mind see) --> **idea** ; **opinion**

Just associate the single characters in these compound words with other related compound words. In short, cross reference them

Also see [认识 vs 知道 based on glyph origins](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22253/%e8%ae%a4%e8%af%86-vs-%e7%9f%a5%e9%81%93-based-on-glyph-origins/22264#22264)

Answer (score 0):

建议 - Suggest, offer an idea.

意见 - One's idea, opinion.

讓我提供一個建议, 看大家的意见如何. Allow me to provide a suggestion, and see everybody's idea/opinion.

這是我的建议, 你的意见如何? This is my suggestion, how you feel about it (based on your idea/opinion).

我建议如此進行, 你有意见嗎? I suggest proceed with this way, do you have a different idea/opinion.

我的意见和你的建议背道而馳. My idea/opinion is opposite to your suggestion.

Here is a pair that may confuse you, but would help if you can figure out the differences.

我不贊同你的建议. I don't agree with your suggestion (I disapprove of the idea provided)

我不贊同你的意见. I don't agree with your idea/opinion (I disapprove of the thought).