# Differences between 知识，知，识，知感 and 认识？

Tags: translation, grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, syntax

“知识” 两个字我始终认为它是要分开来谈的，“知” 就是知感，“识” 就是认识。所谓 “知感” 就是别人告诉你、说给你听、要求你记住的那一部分。但只有这一部分是不够的，还要有认识、思考。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 22.

I would appreciate if you explain the differences between these: 知识，知，识，知感，认识. I think I need your help to clarify all the aspects of this paragraph.

Also, I don't understand the literal translation of this part: “知识” 两个字我始终认为它是要分开来谈的。

I am at this point:

“知识” (knowledge)两个字(two characters)我(I)始终(from the beginning to end or always)认为(believed)它是(it)要(needs)分开(to separate)来(?)谈(to discuss)的。

How to make it make sense? Especially this part: 分开来谈。For example, about the 来, according to wiktionary it can mean "Meaningless particle for rhythmic purposes". ??

Also, I don't understand the combination of 两个字 ... 它。I mean, I would either write 两个字 ... 它们：“知识” 两个字我始终认为它们是要分开来谈的， or 一个词 ... 它：“知识” 一个词我始终认为它是要分开来谈的. What am I missing?

Comment: please read https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22253/%e8%ae%a4%e8%af%86-vs-%e7%9f%a5%e9%81%93-based-on-glyph-origins/22264#22264

Comment: I don't know about HSK, who write it or who published it, but "知感"... it is never a correct word for my understanding. There's only “感知”，means sensoring , or feeling, or "知道“, means knowing.  
If it is not your typo, then I'm going to question the editor of HSK. "知感"... is so...wrong...or...so fake... Never hear any Chinese people saying like that in my life. This is the first time I ever saw it.

Comment: I know there is 感知, 感覺 and 知覺, but not 知感. In fact, I have not seen it used anywhere before.

Answer (score 0):

The metaphysics of the mind! How do we know what we know?

感知：perceive, perception, awareness

But 知感 is odd. Probably not many people know what 知感 is really supposed to mean. It's idiomatic.

百度 has this for 知感：知感，拼音zhī gǎn，汉语词语，意思是知恩感德。So the basic meaning of 知感 is "very grateful", according to 百度， but I believe the author uses 知感 here to mean "a feeling of recognition" or "a feeling of knowing"

There are two idioms: 知恩不报：ungrateful and 知恩图报：grateful and wishing to repay after some fashion. Perhaps the author was thinking of these two.

Funnily enough, "knowledge" is made of 2 parts: know and ledge.

knowledge: from Middle English: cnawlece "acknowledgment of a superior, honor, worship;" In Modern English this would be acknowledge. Old English cnáwan mixed up the senses of knowledge and acknowledge.

它：it (the word 知识）
分开来谈：talk about separately

“知识” 两个字我始终认为它是要分开来谈的，
I always believe "knowledge", these two characters need to be talked about separately,
“知” 就是知感，
"know" is to have a, perhaps unclear, feeling of knowing,
“识” 就是认识。
"ledge" is recognize (or know)
所谓 “知感” 就是别人告诉你、说给你听、要求你记住的那一部分。
(The) so-called "feeling of knowing" is when other people tell you, say they will let you hear something, and require you to remember that part.
但只有这一部分是不够的，
But just hearing that part is not enough,
还要有认识、思考。
one must also recognize and reflect.

Comment: It's the first time I've every heard of "知感", and the Baidu explanation makes it ever more strange. It could just be a "new word" of Internet/social media influence, just like lol, or cu, 2u..., but no, it's not a proper Chinese word, not even with the explanation from Baidu. You could say something like "...要知感恩...“. However, in this phrase, it should be split as "要知（道）“+”感恩“, but not "...知感...." :s

Answer (score 0):

- 知识 - knowledge
- 知 - know
- 识 - recognizing, distinguishing
- 感知 - perception (I think 知感, which means 知恩感德, is a miss-use)
- 認识 - cognition

“知识” (knowledge)两个字(two characters)我(I)始终(always)认为(believe/consider/think)它是(it)要(needs)分开(to separate)来(come)谈(to discuss)的, “知” 就是(in the same way as)知感(perception)，“识” 就是(in the same way as)认识(cognition)。

Come to discuss **the word(单词)** "知识(knowledge)", I always think/consider it needs to be separated into (two parts) - "知(know)", in the same way as "perception", and “识(recognizing)", in the same way as "cognition".

Note: “知识” is a two-character(字) "word".

Answer (score 0):

知识 is knowledge. You cannot split it up and examine each individual character to try and guess the meaning of the group. It's as absurd as trying to split "butterfly" into butter and fly, or understand into under and stand.

There are many characters groups in Chinese which ought to be taken as a whole. For example, 人生, 天下, 江湖, 規矩

Answer (score 0):

知, 识, and 知识 are three words in Chinese.

知 is 感性. You feel and perceive it from the outside world.

识 is 理性. You understand it after thinking, comparing, and reasoning by yourself.

知识 is a noun that means the result of your study on something that you not only know but also understand.

In Chinese, a compound word, such as 知识, is not just simply put two or more characters together, but it extends to a much deeper, more complex, and more abstract meaning or concept.

In some cases, people use 知 and 识 interchangeably. For example,

知我者谓我心忧, 不知我者谓我何求.

知 actually means 识, 懂我的人知道我为国家忧虑，不懂我的人以为我是追求钱财.

Answer (score 0):

I am chinese. For me, chinese to english: I always think we should separate 'knowledge' to 2 words to talk.
我是中国人。 对我来说，汉译英：我一直认为我们应该把“知识”分成两个词来谈论。